# which ide now can support go1.18 workspace

Tags: go, goland

I use this command to init workspace

```
go work init mypkg example
```

My code can run but the goland 2021.3 can not support it very well.Is there a way to solve it？

Answer (score 3):

I believe goland has its own parsing implementation, so you will have to wait for an official update.

If you want to try out go1.18beta you can use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or any other [editor/IDE which uses gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls#editors). The [go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) in VSCode uses [gopls](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/gopls) which provides some support for [generics](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/advanced.md#working-with-generic-code) and [workspaces](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md#workspace-module-experimental). It is not perfect yet, but that is to be expected with beta software.